# How do I permanently delete an email account in Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

How do I permanently delete an email account in Exchange 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this PowerShell Command to remove a mailbox account permanently:

```
Remove-Mailbox -Identity 'mailboxUserName' -Permanent $true
```